How to partially dismiss a ModalBottomSheet in Jetpack Compose?
I building a quiz app where a ModalBottomSheet pops up after the user answers a question.

When dismissed, the sheet reveals the question details,
but the drag handle should remain visible so the user can review the explanation.

How would i implement this?

first add this library from github:
https://github.com/skydoves/FlexibleBottomSheet
dependencies {
    // compose material
    implementation("com.github.skydoves:flexible-bottomsheet-material:0.1.4")

    // compose material3
    implementation("com.github.skydoves:flexible-bottomsheet-material3:0.1.4")
}

then try this bottomsheet:
FlexibleBottomSheet(
  onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
  sheetState = rememberFlexibleBottomSheetState(
    flexibleSheetSize = FlexibleSheetSize(
      fullyExpanded = 0.9f,
      intermediatelyExpanded = 0.5f,
      slightlyExpanded = 0.15f,
    ),
    isModal = true,
    skipSlightlyExpanded = false,
  ),
  containerColor = Color.Black,
) {
  Text(
    modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .padding(8.dp),
    text = "This is Flexible Bottom Sheet",
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    color = Color.White,
  )
}

